# Material UI OutlinedInput and InputLabel overlap

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I solve the overlap issue in `InputLabel` and `OutlinedInput` in Material UI?

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/materialuioutlinedinputandinputlabeloverlap-tvu0v)

```
<FormControl>
    <InputLabel htmlFor="my-input">Email address</InputLabel>
    <OutlinedInput id="my-input" aria-describedby="my-helper-text" />
    <FormHelperText id="my-helper-text">
        We'll never share your email.
    </FormHelperText>
</FormControl>

<hr />
<br />
<FormControl>
    <InputLabel shrink={true} htmlFor="my-input">
        Email address
    </InputLabel>
    <OutlinedInput id="my-input" aria-describedby="my-helper-text" />
    <FormHelperText id="my-helper-text">
        We'll never share your email.
    </FormHelperText>
</FormControl>
```

Result:

[image]

I tried the `shrink={true}` but it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add "label" attribute in OutlinedInput tag.

```html
 <OutlinedInput id="my-input" aria-describedby="my-helper-text"   label="Email address"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. One would expect that because of the `id` and `htmlFor`, material ui can calculate this and there should be no need to duplicate that label.